# Show that $\|(\lambda - T)^{-1}\| \leq 1/(1-|\lambda|)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T \in L(X)$ satisfy $\|Tx\| =\|x\|$ for each $x \in X$. Suppose that the range of $T \neq X$ and let $0 < |\lambda| < 1$. Assuming that $λ \in \rho(T)$, show that $\|(λ − T)^{−1}\| \leq 1/(1−|λ|)$. Here $\rho(T)$ is the resolvent set of $T$.

I need this intermediate step in proving that $\sigma(T)$ is the unit disk.

Comment: If $\sigma(T)=D$ then $|\lambda|<1$ cannot be in the resolvent set. Are you trying proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda \in \rho(T)$ then the above inequality should hold. I have a theorem in my lecture notes which contradicts that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My theory of resolvents is a bit rusty but I'll give it a try.

Let $y$ be in the domain of $(\lambda-T)^{-1}$, define $x = (\lambda-T)^{-1}y$. Then
$$\|(\lambda-T)^{-1}y\| = \|x\|.$$

Using the assumption about $T$, we know that
$$\|x\| = \|Tx\| = \|(\lambda-T)x - \lambda x\| \le \|(\lambda - T)x\| + |\lambda| \|x\| = \|y\| + |\lambda|\|x\|,$$
the inequality being the triangle inequality for norm. Denoting $\|x\| = u$, we find

$$\begin{aligned}
u &\le \|y\| + |\lambda|u, \\
(1 - |λ|) u &\le \|y\|, \\
u &\le \frac{\|y\|}{1-|\lambda|},
\end{aligned}$$

(note that in the last step we needed that $|λ| < 1$), so for all $y$ in the domain of $(\lambda-T)^{-1}$,

$$\|(\lambda-T)^{-1}y\| \le \frac{\|y\|}{1-|\lambda|}.$$

The rest is the density of such $y$ and the definition of a norm of an operator.

Comment: Looks pretty good

Comment: Shouldn't $|\lambda| < 1$, else the $\leq$ would not hold. The rest of the answer looks good! Thanks.

Comment: @user317992 True, it should.

Comment: Yes, you're right. A greater $λ$ would reverse the inequality sign. I was wondering why that assumption was there.

Comment: @user317992 For $|\lambda|>1$ one can use estimation via [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit @A.G.!